# Persist a Cursor in PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a process that needs to iterate over an entire MongoDB collection.  The collection is large and would be worked on a chunk at a time with the process going to sleep and saving state after it completed analyzing a portion of the collection.

Conceptually I would like to do the following:

```
def processCollection():
    chunkStart, chunkEnd = <restore state>
    for document in collection[chunkStart:chunkEnd]
        <do work>
    <write new chunkStart and chunkEnd state>
    <sleep>
```

Is there a way to persist a cursor in PyMongo or do I need to rely on a last modified timestamp or similar to keep track of what has been processed?